# Leaflet Markercluster and Timeline in sync

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping

So I have been trying to figure how to use the markercluster and timeline plug in in sync to show a temporal animation of points. As some of the point data overlaps a cluster is needed to be able to select all the data. Unfortunately I have been having issues with using the pointToLayer function to create a marker and add to my marker cluster.here is a sample of what I tried with no luck:

```
    var timeline = L.timeline(data, {
      formatDate: function(date){
        return moment(date).format("YYYY");},
     pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
      var marker = L.marker(latlng);
      marker.bindPopup("test");
      markers.addLayer(marker);
      return markers;
     }
```